# How to show a modal only once per user?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a Flask application that allows different users to register and log in. For this I have implemented sessions in my code. At the fist page new users arrive at, there is a modal welcoming them to the platform. I want to be able to show this modal only once to newly registered and logged in users. Alterations of this question have been answered in Stackoverflow but I tried them all and no answer helped me out.

So here is my code:

html page:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
INDEX
{% endblock %}

{% block main %}
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
       <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
           <h5 class="modal-title">Welcome!</h5>
           <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Welcome to the index page! Here you can trade to your heart's content with us by your side!<span class="badge">By <a href="https://webdevrahul007.w3spaces.com/"></a>Rahul jangid</span></p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
           <!--this closes, see what ull do -->
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Move On</button>
           <!--Here make sure to implement the next functionality. Look at changing the color of the popover. Also add some popovers.-->
       </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style ="color:red">Symbol</th>
            <th style ="color:red">Name</th>
            <th style ="color:red">Stock Shares</th>
            <th style ="color:red">Price</th>
            <th style ="color:red">Sum</th>
        </tr>
    <tbody>
        {% for stock in stocks %}
        <tr>
          <td style ="color:red">{{stock.symbol}}</td>
          <td style ="color:red">{{stock.name}}</td>
          <td style ="color:red">{{stock.shares}}</td>
          <td style ="color:red">{{stock.price | usd}}</td>
          <td style ="color:red">{{stock.total | usd}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        <tr>
            <td style ="color:red">CASH</td>
            <td colspan ="3"></td>
            <td style ="color:red"> {{cash | usd}}</td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <td style ="color:red">Initial Cash</td>
        <td colspan ="3"></td>
        <td style ="color:red">{{ total_cash | usd }} </td>

    </tfoot>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Check if user saw the modal
    var key = 'hadModal',
        hadModal = localStorage.getItem(key);

    // Show the modal only if new user
    if (!hadModal) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }

    // If modal is displayed, store that in localStorage
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        localStorage.setItem(key, true);
    })
});
```

The problem with this code is that the modal showed only once and never again. (P.S. I have also tried the cookie approach, which didn't work either) It showed up just for one user and not for the other newly registered one. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I want to show this modal only once to newly registered and logged in users", "The problem with this code is that the modal showed only once and never again". Meaning? You want unregistered users to keep seeing it? What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps create an x button that if it's clicked the local storage key is written? Obviously, if the user accesses your site from a different device, it's not going to have that key, and the modal will be shown again.

Comment: I lets say I have 3 users a,b, and c. User a has been a user for a while so he has logged in more than once. User b and c  just registered and have logged in for the first time. I want bot users b and c to see the modal once in their first log in but I do not want user a to see it. When I run my code, I registered and logged in as user b and saw the modal, but it never showed for user c and all the other newly registered users. Is this clear?

Comment: This is because you are using the same user agent with the same origin - `localstorage` applies to all of your interactions from that browser. Clear you browser data, log in as `a` with that browser, then log in as `b` with a different browser. You might see it works as you expect.

Comment: look into local storage.  Store the user in local storage and go from there

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var users = ['email1', 'email2'] //pushes all logged users here

  function checkUsers() { //call this function on every log in
    // Check if user saw the modal
    var key = 'hadModal',
      hadModal = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));

    var loggedUserEmail // 

    // Show the modal only if new user
    if (!hadModal) {
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
      users.push(loggedUserEmail) // push new user in users
    } else {
      if (!hadModal.includes(loggedUserEmail)) { // check if logged user is new
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        users.push(loggedUserEmail) // push new user in users
      }
    }

    // If modal is displayed, store that in localStorage
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(users));
    })
  }
});
```